# Failed to 'network-remove' GameObject because has no PhotonView

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am developing an game app using Unity3d and Photon.
I got this error when calling 'PhotonNetwork.Destroy(hpBar.gameObject);'.
But, hpBar has a PhotonView component. I wonder why this happens.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What error are you talking about? And you should post the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: The title is the error message. The code is simple which is 'PhotonNetwork.Destroy(hpBar.gameObject);  'hpBar' is supposed to be deleted when this code is executed, but the error occurred instead.

Comment: @peacetype Thanks for making me review my code. I found my mistake. :)